# Docker change .gitconfig with token for private repo access

Tags: git, docker, github, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been digging to solve the problem during docker build stages of accessing private repos. Seems like using 'tokens' is the easiest and reasonably secure way of achieving this.

I came across an [article](https://divan.github.io/posts/go_get_private/), explaining this. In the comments someone suggested an improvement to add a github token. I cannot get it to work inside docker. How can I change the `.gitconfig` and have git always use the token?

This command needs to be change to using the token:

```
RUN echo "[url \"git@github.com:\"]\n\tinsteadOf = https://github.com/" >> /root/.gitconfig
```

The comment:

> A better approach would be to generate an api token with read only
>   access to that repo and using something like `git config --global
>   url."https://${TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`.
>   This way you don't need a wrapper script or ssh host key checking, nor
>   do you need bake your all access

It would be great if someone could help me cross the bridge. Thx

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by running the following RUN command. Make sure, to have the correct rights when generating the token on github.

```
FROM golang:1.9
RUN git config --global url."https://USERNAME:TOKEN@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of RUN you can use COPY command.

```
COPY .gitconfig /root/.gitconfig
```